# Як найкраще перекласти “off-topic”?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Нещодавно більше людей стали проводити час вдома та спілкуватися з різними мережевими спільнотами віддалено. Відповідно, це слово набуло особливої актуальності оскільки все більше й більше людей розміщують на мережевих форумах повідомлення, що абсолютно не мають нічого спільного з початковою темою обговорення.

Наперед повідомляю, що мене не цікавить [пряме калькування англійського першоджерела 'офтопік' як це зробила укрвікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BA). Цікавлять саме питомо українські слова, або новотвори засновані на україномовній основі.

Comment: Будь ласка, уточніть, яке саме формулювання вас цікавить, адже можуть бути різні варіанти. Це має бути звертання до когось чи позначення якогось посту теґом "офтопік", лиш українським варіантом, чи щось третє?

Comment: @P. Vovk не зрозумів питання. Якщо питання в якому контексті я хочу вживати це слово - то у будь-якому контексті де це слово вживається англійською

Comment: Просто цих контекстів може бути більше, аніж на одну відповідь. Було би добре розуміти, на що саме відповідати. Я зараз виклав те, як я це бачу, але, можливо, я щось випустив з поля зору.

Comment: Будь-які безглузді недоречні коментарі, що не стосуються запитання топікстартера, як-то кажуть "не до справи", можна вважати "офф-топік" і безжально видаляти.

Answer (score 6):

Попередній [коментар](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/6200/240) досить вичерпний, можу додати хіба що *недоладно, недоладність* як характеристика повідомлення, що не відповідає обговорюваній тематиці.
Як сайт або форум, де користувачі обговорюють усілякі дурниці (фіксується і таке значення https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Off%20Topic), – вебхащі, інтернетрі

Answer (score 5):

Спиратимусь на [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/oftop), адже там уже трохи подумали про це, але надаватиму свої варіанти.

1. Якщо йдеться про повідомлення когось про те, що його відповідь не пасує до теми обговорення:

   - Ви відійшли від теми.
   - (Це) поза темою.
   - (Це) не стосується предмету обговорення.
   - (Це) обговорюється в іншому місці.

Варіанти можна за потреби об'єднувати чи модифікувати.

2. Якщо треба коротко сказати або просто позначити, що щось поза темою:

   - Поза темою.
   - Нерелевантно.
   - Не в тему.
   - Інша тема.
   - Ні до чого.
   - Не тут.
   - Хибне місце.

Comment: «Поза темою» здається більш-менш універальним еквівалентом.